# Cabal installation fails on M1

Tags: cabal, cardano

I want to add Cardano to Express project and followed the steps in documentation: https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/installing-cardano-node/#macos.

Unfortunately, “cabal build all” step failed after three hours of running.

I found a [similar question](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/issues/3506) on GitHub, it was advised to uninstall Libsodium, but I get an error for that as well:

```
brew uninstall libsodium

Error: No such keg: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/libsodium
```

Here is my **terminal** with the previous commands ran successfully:

```
"package trace-dispatcher" >> cabal.project.local
 cardano-node % echo "  ghc-options: -Wwarn" >> cabal.project.local

 cardano-node % echo "" >> cabal.project.local
 cardano-node % echo "package HsOpenSSL" >> cabal.project.local
 cardano-node % echo "  flags: -homebrew-openssl" >> cabal.project.local

 cardano-node % echo "" >> cabal.project.local
 cardano-node % cabal update
Downloading the latest package lists from:
- hackage.haskell.org
- cardano-haskell-packages
Package list of hackage.haskell.org is up to date at index-state 2023-05-18T11:10:29Z
Updated package list of cardano-haskell-packages to the index-state 2023-05-17T06:53:34Z
```

Please see the failing **final message**:

```
[63 of 68] Compiling Cardano.Node.Tracing.Tracers ( src/Cardano/Node/Tracing/Tracers.hs, /Users/Lilit_Mazmanyan/cardano-src/cardano-node/dist-newstyle/build/aarch64-osx/ghc-8.10.7/cardano-node-8.0.0/build/Cardano/Node/Tracing/Tracers.o, /Users/Lilit_Mazmanyan/cardano-src/cardano-node/dist-newstyle/build/aarch64-osx/ghc-8.10.7/cardano-node-8.0.0/build/Cardano/Node/Tracing/Tracers.dyn_o )
[64 of 68] Compiling Cardano.Node.Tracing.API ( src/Cardano/Node/Tracing/API.hs, /Users/Lilit_Mazmanyan/cardano-src/cardano-node/dist-newstyle/build/aarch64-osx/ghc-8.10.7/cardano-node-8.0.0/build/Cardano/Node/Tracing/API.o, /Users/Lilit_Mazmanyan/cardano-src/cardano-node/dist-newstyle/build/aarch64-osx/ghc-8.10.7/cardano-node-8.0.0/build/Cardano/Node/Tracing/API.dyn_o )
[65 of 68] Compiling Cardano.Node.Tracing.Documentation ( src/Cardano/Node/Tracing/Documentation.hs, /Users/Lilit_Mazmanyan/cardano-src/cardano-node/dist-newstyle/build/aarch64-osx/ghc-8.10.7/cardano-node-8.0.0/build/Cardano/Node/Tracing/Documentation.o, /Users/Lilit_Mazmanyan/cardano-src/cardano-node/dist-newstyle/build/aarch64-osx/ghc-8.10.7/cardano-node-8.0.0/build/Cardano/Node/Tracing/Documentation.dyn_o )
[66 of 68] Compiling Cardano.Node.Configuration.Logging ( src/Cardano/Node/Configuration/Logging.hs, /Users/Lilit_Mazmanyan/cardano-src/cardano-node/dist-newstyle/build/aarch64-osx/ghc-8.10.7/cardano-node-8.0.0/build/Cardano/Node/Configuration/Logging.o, /Users/Lilit_Mazmanyan/cardano-src/cardano-node/dist-newstyle/build/aarch64-osx/ghc-8.10.7/cardano-node-8.0.0/build/Cardano/Node/Configuration/Logging.dyn_o )
[67 of 68] Compiling Cardano.Tracing.Tracers ( src/Cardano/Tracing/Tracers.hs, /Users/Lilit_Mazmanyan/cardano-src/cardano-node/dist-newstyle/build/aarch64-osx/ghc-8.10.7/cardano-node-8.0.0/build/Cardano/Tracing/Tracers.o, /Users/Lilit_Mazmanyan/cardano-src/cardano-node/dist-newstyle/build/aarch64-osx/ghc-8.10.7/cardano-node-8.0.0/build/Cardano/Tracing/Tracers.dyn_o )
[68 of 68] Compiling Cardano.Node.Run ( src/Cardano/Node/Run.hs, /Users/Lilit_Mazmanyan/cardano-src/cardano-node/dist-newstyle/build/aarch64-osx/ghc-8.10.7/cardano-node-8.0.0/build/Cardano/Node/Run.o, /Users/Lilit_Mazmanyan/cardano-src/cardano-node/dist-newstyle/build/aarch64-osx/ghc-8.10.7/cardano-node-8.0.0/build/Cardano/Node/Run.dyn_o )
cabal: Failed to build exe:chain-sync-client-with-ledger-state from
cardano-client-demo-0.1.0.0.
Failed to build exe:scan-blocks from cardano-client-demo-0.1.0.0.
Failed to build exe:scan-blocks-pipelined from cardano-client-demo-0.1.0.0.
Failed to build exe:stake-credential-history from cardano-client-demo-0.1.0.0.
Failed to build exe:gen-plutus from plutus-scripts-bench-1.0.0.0.
```